# In Egorov's Theorem, is almost everywhere same as point-wise?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence

I am studying about Egorov's Theorem.

My teaching assistant said to me that Egorov's theorem is roughly like the following statement:

Under two conditions which are $|E|\lt+\infty$ and $|f|\lt+\infty$ ,
$$f_k \to f ~~\text{point-wisely} \Longrightarrow f_k \to f ~~\text{uniformly}$$

---

In the textbook, there is no word about point-wise. The definition of textbook version is like the following:

**Egorov's Theorem.**
Suppose that $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions which converges almost everywhere in a set $E$ of finite measure to a finite limit $f$. Then given $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is a closed subset $F$ of $E$ such that $|E-F| \lt \varepsilon$ and $\{f_k\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $F$.

---

I am not sure that almost everywhere is considered as pointwise. Can someone tell me which are same or different? If they are different, please give a counter example. Although I know the definition of each of them, I cannot make example. :(

Comment: Yes here almost everywhere means almost everywhere point wise.

Comment: @Timkinsella you mean a.e is equal to a.e. pointwise? So a.e. is not equal to pointwise, right??

Comment: point-wise convergence of functions means the sequence of numbers $f_n(x)$ converges to the number $f(x)$ for every $x$. When we say convergence we usually mean point-wise convergence. Converges almost every where means that the set of $x$ where the sequence do not converge has a measure 0. I'm not sure what you want to differentiate?

Answer (score 3):

First let me remind you of the standard definitions:

- $f_k\to f$ **pointwise** on $E$ if $\forall x\in E: f_k(x)\to f(x)$.
- $f_k\to f$ **almost everywhere** on $E$ if $\exists$ measurable $N\subseteq E: m(N)=0, \forall x\in E-N: f_k(x)\to f(x)$. Such a set $N$ is called **negligible**.

---

Observe that if $f_k\to f$ pointwise then $f_k\to f$ almost everywhere with the negligible set $N:=\emptyset$, but not vice versa: let $E:=\{0,1\}, \forall k: f_k:E\to\mathbb{R}, f_k(x):=kx$. Then $f_k\to 0$ almost everywhere (with $N:=\{1\}$) but not pointwise.

Hence your teaching assistant cited a version of Egorov's Theorem weaker than the one given in your book (though it's not marginally weaker, rather it's negligibly weaker, so to speak).